# How to change text to something else based on the current URL?

Tags: javascript, url, text, title

I'm working on a store site, and would like to have the collection title that is displayed on each page to be displayed as a basic breadcrumb like "WOMEN > JEWELRY". The problem I'm having is the only thing that is displayed on every collection page is "WOMEN".

I'd like to change this text to the basic breadcrumb based on the current pages URL. For example, the URL for the main women's collection is http://www.shopfashionworthy.com/collections/women, but the URL for the individual women's jewelry products is http://www.shopfashionworthy.com/collections/women/jewelry. I'd like to have some way of saying "If the URL is http://www.shopfashionworthy.com/collections/women/jewelry, change the collection title to WOMENS > JEWELRY". Hope I'm making sense.

The current code for the collection titles is:

```
<!-- START EXCERPT -->
<div id="excerpt">
<h1 class="title{% if collection.description.size > 0 %}
    {% else %} nodesc{% endif %}">{{ collection.title | escape }}</h1>
    {% if collection.description.size > 0 %}
{{ collection.description }}{% endif %}
</div>
<!-- END EXCERPT -->
```

Comment: Don't create the breadcrumb using JavaScript, make it using your server-side language. Otherwise search engines won't read it and user without JavaScript won't be able to see it either.

Answer (score 0):

The `window.location.pathname` method is what you're looking for.

For the example page you mentioned, it returns the following string:

`/collections/women/jewelry`

From here, you can run `search` to find if the string contains `jewelry`:

```
var thisString = window.location.pathname;

function doSearch(regex, string) {
  var findMatch = string.search(regex);
  if (findMatch !== -1) return true;
  else return false;
}
if (doSearch(/jewelry/, thisString) === true) {
  // create breadcrumb navigation
}​
```

Comment: Thanks Nick! How would I add this to my existing code? Also, should I replace // create breadcrumb navigation with the actual breadcrumb code? Probably dumb questions, but I want it to work. Thanks again!